# Settings page above CPT page in admin section

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, menus, add-menu-page

I'm creating a plugin which generates a handfull or custom post types (CPT).  I've create a top level menu in the admin left sidebar using `add_menu_page()`.  I then added all CPTs to this menu using `register_post_type()`'s `show_in_menu` option.  I also created a plugin settings page using `add_submenu_page()`, which I also added to the top menu.

My problem is that I can't get the settings page to appear above the CPT pages in the submenu.     I make the `register_post_type()` call in an "init" action, and I make the `add_submenu_page()` call in a "admin_menu" action (which happens after "init").  So, it makes sense that the CPT pages come first.  I can't move the `register_post_type()` calls to later in the process (it's too late to register a CPT, and I can't move the `add_submenu_page()` earlier (it's not defined earlier).

Do I just have to live with it?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `menu_order` filter hook to change the order

```
function custom_menu_order($menu_ord) {
       if (!$menu_ord) return true;
       return array('settings_page.php', 'edit.php?post_type=CTP1','edit.php?post_type=CTP2','edit.php?post_type=CTP3');
}

add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
add_filter('menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to reorder submenu items.  This would only reorder top menu items.